# While statement not repeating SOAP/XML/cURL content

Tags: php, xml, curl, soap

I Have this code

```
$con = mysqli_connect(**);
$con2 = mysqli_connect(**);

$sta = mysqli_query($con2, "SELECT a, b FROM c WHERE a LIKE '%t%' AND d > '0' ");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sta, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $na = $row['a'];
    $arr = explode("-", $na, 2);
    $cb = $arr[0];

    $intemp = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM o WHERE c = '$arr[0]' AND k = '$arr[1]' ");
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($intemp);
    if (!$num_rows > 0) {
        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO o *works*");

// *********

        $RSTCI = $arr[1]; 
        if ($RSTCI != '') $pars .= '<ns1:c>' . $RSTCI . '</ns1:c>';
        $RSTIT = $row['stat_user']; 
        if ($RSTIT != '') $pars .= '<ns1:i>' . $RSTIT . '</ns1:i>';
        $act = 'rST';
        $ns1 = 'rSTR';  
        $user = $row['user'];

        $loc = '**';
        $url = '**';
        $soap_data = '<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" env:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="**"><env:Header><ns1:Action>/' . $act . '</ns1:Action><ns1:c>' . $arr[0] . '</ns1:c>' .
          '</env:Header><env:Body><ns1:' . $ns1 . '>' . $pars . '</ns1:' . $ns1 . '></env:Body></env:Envelope>';
        $headers = array(
                            "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
                            "Accept: text/xml",
                            "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                            "Pragma: no-cache",
                            "SOAPAction: /" . $act, 
                            "Content-length: " . strlen($soap_data),
                        );
                $url = $loc;
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, "**");
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "**");
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $soap_data); // the SOAP request

                $response = curl_exec($ch);


        $foo = str_replace('<', '&lt;', str_replace('>', '&gt;', $soap_data));
        $respfoo = str_replace('<', '&lt;', str_replace('>', '&gt;', $response));
        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO *works*");
        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO *works*");

        $wait = curl_init("**"); 
        curl_setopt($wait, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_exec($wait);
        curl_close($wait);
// *********        
    }
}
```

?>

I know this is may be harder to understand due to removal of sensitive information. What happens is that mysqli_query $sta returns 3 or so results. The following 'while' should loop 3x (number of returned rows), and it does so until I add the SOAP and cURL lines between // *********.
When I delete all those lines, the info from query $sta is inserted into database $con just fine 3x

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO o *works*");
```

so I know this works.
What could be causing the script to only run once when run with the SOAP request? Nothing else changes in between tests. Also, the SOAP request works just fine and is sent, once in the loop (of 3) or as a script by itself, no errors there. My goal is to repeat the SOAP request however many times there are rows in $sta, because each SOAP request's data changes depending on the data in those rows.

Comment: I have partially resolved this by POSTing via cURL with the variable data in the URL to a different .php page with the SOAP array, which GETs the data variables. This works in the looped manner. I have not found out why the above code does not loop multiple times, but I have found an old question somewhere with the same basic problem, except in a different language than PHP (Java, iirc).